# Passing a struct to pthread_create, undefined values after cast?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pthreads

I am trying to pass a struct as a parameter to pthread_create and seem to be getting some strange results.

The struct has two members, first one being an int and the second one is a function pointer:

```
typedef struct
{
  int num;
  void (*func)(int);
} foo_t;
```

The function I am trying to use within the struct:

```
void myfunc(int mynum)
{
   printf("mynum: %d\n", mynum);
}
```

This is the declaration of the struct I will be passing to my thread:

```
foo_t f;
f.num = 42;
f.func = &myfunc;
```

The call to pthread_create:

```
pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, mythreadfunc, &f);
```

And finally, my thread function:

```
void mythreadfunc(void *foo)
{
   foo_t f = *(foo_t *)foo;
   printf("num: %d\n", f.num); // Prints: num: 32776 (undefined?)
   (*f.func)(f.num);  // Segfaults (again, undefined?)
...
```

It seems that the cast within mythreadfunc doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post complete code? It's quite likely the bug is in code you haven't shown us. (Such as `f` going out of scope before the thread can access it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It was a scope issue as you've guessed, next time I'll try to post a more "self-contained" example, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your `foo_t f` by reference. If you are changing your `f` from your `pthread_create`-calling function or somewhere else, for example leaving the corresponding scope would remove/delete `f` from the stack, then your reference inside your thread is (most likely) invalid. At least you should not access it anymore.

Use pointers with dynamically allocated variables instead.

*Though I can not prove that this is happening with the code you have presented.*

**Edit:**

A pointer is used to store the address of an object/variable. In `C/C++` you can have it point to a dynamically allocated memory segment. Look up `malloc/`[`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) for this. You can do what is called `dereferencing` with pointers and access the objecct/variable itself.

You can pass the pointer per value, which means, that you won't pass the object/variable itself, but the address(= position) of the object/variable inside your RAM. The memory management of dynamically allocated varialbes/object lies in the responsibility of the programmer, so your object won't be deleted when the scope of the pointer ends, only the pointer which stores the address will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was a scope issue as you've mentioned. If I declare `f` as a global it seems to work okay. I couldn't quite figure out the pointer bit of your answer though -- wouldn't I have the same scope problem even if I passed a pointer to `f` in `pthread_Create()`?

Comment: Declaring it as a global is the worst possible solution. Papergay did not say "pass a pointer". You're already passing a pointer, and that's the only possible thing you can pass. What Papergay said is to pass a pointer to an object with *dynamic storage duration* (an object obtained by `malloc`) rather than a pointer to an object with *automatic storage duration* (local variable).

Comment: I updated my post a little to give you an idea for the use of pointers. But it is way too much to post a tutorial. There are many online tutorials and documentations/books anyway, so I doubt you will have problems...

Comment: Thanks, so essentially I should malloc() an area in the heap the size of my struct, set the values accordingly and pass the pointer to that in the `pthread_create` call -- does that sounds about right?

Comment: Yes it does. But don't forget the casting. A pointer's type tells the compiler how to interpret the object it is pointing to. `pthread_create` requires a `void*`-type, so you have to cast it back to your actual type, since `void` contains no type information and thus would be useless for the compiler. *Btw, sorry that I could not find a `malloc()` tutorial right out of the blue...new is just for c++*

Comment: No worries, I was able to use this to get rid of the global variable. I guess I should `free()` the area in heap after I am done with it or maybe just ignore it since it's only a few bytes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ignoring it is not a good practice. There are programs that will never finish and always keep running (-> server). If you loose even one address in your program, it will result in a memory loss since it will never be free*ed again. So do not even get used to it.

Comment: Comment on the downvote please :D Maybe there is stuff to improve. And don't even bother downvoting if you can't/won't...

Comment: Well, I can't see anything wrong with your answer, so an upvote.  It's an obvious and common solution - the new thread takes ownership of the struct and can do what it wishes with it, use it, free it, queue its pointer off to another thread, keep it till it's freed on app close, whatever.  Wot's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Papergay's answer is definitely one solution, but another approach you can use if you want to avoid dynamic allocation is just using synchronization. My favorite approach is putting a semaphore with initial-value zero in the struct and having the parent wait on the semaphore and the child post the semaphore after it's done reading the values out of the structure.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't this cause the same scoping issue though (which will require me to declare this particular struct as a global)?

Comment: No. The caller (of `pthread_create`, in the parent thread) cannot return until it finishes waiting on the semaphore, and thus the struct does not go out of scope until then.

Comment: Ah, okay. I am using `pthread_tryjoin_np` which is a non-blocking version of `pthread_join()` so I guess for this to work I should go back to using `pthread_join()`.

Comment: Huh? That has nothing do do with your question.

Comment: As you can probably tell, this isn't really my strong point. The way I interpreted your answer was: have a semaphore 'flag' within the struct  initialised to 0, which is then set to 1 within the newly created thread whilst checking that within the parent thread that calls `pthread_create`. Is it as simple as that or is there a more elegant way of handling semaphores? (Thanks!)

Comment: An integer variable is not a semaphore. I mean use `sem_init`, `sem_wait`, and `sem_post` with a `sem_t` object inside the struct.

Comment: Looks like I have some reading to do, thanks for the suggestion!